# Bypass MFA for Hybrid Azure AD joined devices and Intune devices

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services

I'm attempting to create a conditional access policy that would skip MFA for Hybrid AD joined devices or devices enrolled in Intune. I've following these 2 articles in regards to the correct settings:

https://www.itpromentor.com/unmanaged-mfa/
https://practical365.com/security/azure-active-directory-conditional-access-enforce-multi-factor-aut...

The policy seems to work for the mobile apps and desktop client apps but it doesn't appear to be working for https://portal.office.com web apps. On the conditional policy, I see no Office 365 portal option to include as an cloud app so I'm prompted for MFA when I launch the Outlook web app. Also, it also disables the Office web apps as well. Is there a fix for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently in preview (as of 10/14/2020):
[image: Conditions -> Device State (Preview) -> Exclude -> Device Hybrid Azure AD Joined]

It is available in conditional access via the `device state (preview)` condition.
Because it is in preview, your experience may vary.
If it is not working for a specific platform, please file a support ticket:
https://aka.ms/azuresupportportal